# Having some problems with Task 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
         #Loop starts here
         # This one provides the option to select one of the three tasks.
 task = input (' Hello! Welcome to Patricia G. Myrons program select task 1, 2 or  3. \n')

         #If the user selects task 1, the program will perform the Simple Divisibility Test 
if task == 1  : 
  print "Task 1 is here! \n"
  print "I can tell you if n is evenly divisible by m \n"
  print "Enter the following"
  n = input("Integer:")
  m = input("Integer:")
  evaluation = n % m
if evaluation == 0:
  print n, "/", m, " evenly divides"
else:
   print n, "/", m, " Sorry, does not evenly divide. Try again!"



  #If the user selects task 2, the program will perform the Prime Test 
if task == 2 : 
   print "Task 2 is here! \n"
   print "I can tell you if the number you enter is prime or not  \n"

   number=int(raw_input("Enter a number "))
elif number <= 1:
   print "Sorry! It is not prime"
else:
   n=2
   check = True
while n != m:
    if m%n == 0:
        print "Yeas! The number you entered is prime"
        check = False
        break
    n+=1
if check == True:
        print "Yeas! The number you entered is prime" 



        #If the user selects task 3, the program will display a list of factor numbers 
if task == 3: 
        print "Task 3 is here! \n"
        print "I can tell you all of the factors of the number you enter \n"
def print_factors(n):

        print("The factors of",n,"are:")
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
  if n % i == 0:
       print(i)


   num = int(input("Enter any number: "))
```

I just finished my program in Python, but I am having some problems with Task 2.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, cut the code down to the minimal example and provide a better problem statement than *"having some problems"*. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? Also, please read [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and review your indentation accordingly.

Comment: @Lafada whitespace has syntactic meaning in Python, in editing you may have removed the problems to which the user refers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I though its new user and dont know how to do format code :)

Comment: @Lafada that may also be true!

Comment: @PatriciaMyron you have so many variable problem, I can discuss in chat if you have time.

Comment: @Lafada Thank you so much for the speedy reply. and yeas do have time.!

Comment: Okey, Let me start chat in chat room.

Comment: Sorry @PatriciaMyron chat room show "Only members of Stack Overflow with at least 20 reputation may talk here "

Comment: Can you give some answer in comments ?

Comment: can I declare all variable before code. because `evaluation` was declare in `if task==1` and used outside `if`.

Comment: I updated my answer, please try to paste it. Its working fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code has indentation problem.

Also the variable used in code is not defined with default value.

I defined all variables default value on top of code.

Please see below code.

```
evaluation = 0
n = 0
m = 0
number = 0
check = False

task = input (' Hello! Welcome to Patricia G. Myrons program select task 1, 2 or  3. \n')

         #If the user selects task 1, the program will perform the Simple Divisibility Test
if task == 1  :
    print "Task 1 is here! \n"
    print "I can tell you if n is evenly divisible by m \n"
    print "Enter the following"
    n = input("Integer:")
    m = input("Integer:")
    evaluation = n % m
    if evaluation == 0:
        print n, "/", m, " evenly divides"
    else:
        print n, "/", m, " Sorry, does not evenly divide. Try again!"



#If the user selects task 2, the program will perform the Prime Test
if task == 2 :
    print "Task 2 is here! \n"
    print "I can tell you if the number you enter is prime or not  \n"

    number=int(raw_input("Enter a number "))
    if number <= 1:
        print "Sorry! It is not prime"
    else:
        n=2
        check = True
    while n != m:
        if m%n == 0:
            print "Yeas! The number you entered is prime"
            check = False
            break
        n+=1
    if check == True:
        print "Yeas! The number you entered is prime"



#If the user selects task 3, the program will display a list of factor numbers
if task == 3:
    print "Task 3 is here! \n"
    print "I can tell you all of the factors of the number you enter \n"
    def print_factors(n):

        print("The factors of",n,"are:")
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                print(i)
    num = print_factors(int(input("Enter any number: ")))
```

Comment: So what was the OP's problem? Was it just formatting? Does this code run? What changes have you made, and has it fixed the problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it has some variable reference missing and formatting problem.

Comment: So please **include that information** in your answer - what have you changed, and why? Just dumping fixed code with *"please try to run this"* is not terribly helpful.

Comment: Your revisions to indentation make the *"variables default value"* totally redundant. Also, `if check == True:` should be `if check:` (and `while: else:` would save you from the flag entirely.